# How to hide circle from inside SVG wave?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have SVG wave and one circle. I need to hide the circle from the inside SVG.

I set `z-index: -3;` on SVG wave and `z-index:-1` on the circle and `z-index: 10;` for example div.

When user scroll then I have to hide that circle from inside SVG. Please check out my second image. The circle is between the wave and example div because of the z-index.

I am not able to explain properly. Hope you understand my issue.

Would you help me out in this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent_div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.about_wave_1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.about_wave {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -3;
}

.ewSzGA path {
  fill: #00a2ff;
}

.bg_blue {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.service-container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.service_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EFBD40;
  position: absolute;
  right: 205px;
  top: 0;
}

.service-container .service_1 h2 {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.example {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="service_1 logo_bg">
      <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_wave_1">
    <div class="about_wave">
      <svg height="50" viewBox="0 0 1440 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208"><path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z" data-reactid="209"></path>
  </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

I need output like
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make like this?

Comment: try my code, i hope this wil help your problem

Comment: Actually yes. Try my code and you'll see it's possible :) @NarendraVerma

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position:absolute` from `.about_wave` class.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parent_div {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

.about_wave_1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.about_wave {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -3;
}

.ewSzGA path {
    fill: #00a2ff;
}

.bg_blue {
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
}

.service-container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.service_1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #EFBD40;
    position: absolute;
    right: 205px;
    top: 0;
}

.service-container .service_1 h2 {
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.example {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="service-container">
        <div class="service_1 logo_bg">
            <h2>text</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about_wave_1">
        <div class="about_wave">
            <svg height="50" viewBox="0 0 1440 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208">
                <path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z"
                    data-reactid="209"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, I need to hide circle from inside SVG.

Comment: The circle is hiding inside SVG (blue wave)

Comment: Wait a min I am uploading the expected output image.

Comment: @NarendraVerma You want to hide till half wave??

Comment: Not half, It depends on the scroll.

Comment: So basically, you don't want to see circle, when the wave scrolls ups, right??

Comment: Actually, That Circle is fixed and once user scroll then the wave and div will go up and from waves, I want to hide the circle.Check out the my output image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161207/discussion-between-noopur-dabhi-and-narendra-verma).

Answer (score 0):

tried in below way, i have added inline styles to these two classes .about_wave_1, .about_wave, check it once may be this will help u, added styles to parent_div

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.about_wave_1{
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 300px;
}
.about_wave{
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -3;
height: 50px;
background-color: #fff;
}
.ewSzGA path{
  fill: #00a2ff;
}
.bg_blue{
background-color:#00a2ff; 
text-align: center; 
height: 200px;
}
.service-container{
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.service_1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
   display: flex;
   background-color: #EFBD40;
   position: absolute;
   right: 205px;
   top: 0;
}
.service-container .service_1 h2{
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.example{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 z-index: 10;
}
object {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent_div{
 height: 600px;
 width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.parent_div:before {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
   left: 0;
   background: #00a2ff;
   z-index: -9;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
 <div class="service-container">
  <div class="service_1 logo_bg"><h2>text</h2></div>
 </div>
 <div class="about_wave_1" style="background:#fff;z-index:9999;">
  <div class="about_wave"  style="background:#fff;z-index:9999;">
   <svg  height="50" id="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208"><path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z" data-reactid="209"></path></svg>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide the circle from inside SVG. Now that circle is showing backside. I need circle front side and backside SVG Wave and circle will not cross the wave.

Comment: Try now again @NarendraVerma

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.parent_div{
 height: 600px;
 width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.parent_div:before {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
   left: 0;
   background: #00a2ff;
   z-index: -2;
}
.about_wave_1{
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 300px;
}
.about_wave{
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -3;
height: 50px;
background-color: #fff;
}
.ewSzGA path{
  fill: #00a2ff;
}

.bg_blue{
background-color:#00a2ff; 
text-align: center; 
height: 200px;
}

.service-container{
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.service_1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
   display: flex;
   background-color: #EFBD40;
   position: absolute;
   right: 205px;
   top: 0;
}
.service-container .service_1 h2{
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.example{
 background-color: #ff0000;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 border:1px solid #000;
 z-index: 10;
}
object {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="service-container">
      <div class="service_1 logo_bg"> <h2>text</h2></div>
    </div>
<div class="about_wave_1" style="background:#fff;z-index:9999;">
 <div class="about_wave"  style="background:#fff;z-index:9999;">
  <svg  height="50" id="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208"><path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z" data-reactid="209"></path>
  </svg>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide the circle from inside.Now that circle is showing backside. I need circle front side and backside SVG Wave and circle will not cross the wave.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made it more complicated than it need to be.

I simplified the example, a bit. Then all I did to get the effect was to turn the SVG into two half-SVGs. One for the top part of the wave, and one for the bottom. Then I simply put the top half at the back with `z-index: -1`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent_div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.about_wave_1,
.about_wave_2 {
  position: relative;
}

.about_wave_1 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.about_wave_1 svg,
.about_wave_2 svg {
  display: block;
}

.ewSzGA path {
  fill: #00a2ff;
}

.service-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
}

.service_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EFBD40;
  position: absolute;
  right: 205px;
  top: 0;
}

.service-container .service_1 h2 {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.example {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <div class="service-container">
    <div class="service_1 logo_bg">
      <h2>text</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_wave_1">
    <svg height="25" viewBox="0 0 1440 25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208"><path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z" data-reactid="209"></path>
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="about_wave_2">
    <svg height="25" viewBox="0 25 1440 25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sc-gqjmRU ewSzGA" data-reactid="208"><path d="M0 39.5062C144.0016 39.5062 144.0016 0 288.0032 0c143.9936 0 143.9936 39.5062 287.9873 39.5062C719.9842 39.5062 719.9842 0 863.9858 0s144.0016 39.5062 288.0032 39.5062C1295.9905 39.5062 1295.9905 0 1440 0v50H0V39.5062z" data-reactid="209"></path>
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```